# Get active window information using C# on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

Prerequisites. Visual Studio for Mac, Mono, C#

I'm porting existing C# application from Windows to Mac. And what I currently need is to get information about currently active window/process. Just user-friendly application name and window title.

Windows code uses Win API for this like GetForegroundWindow. Does something similar exist on Mac? Is there some way to get required information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `FrontmostApplication` of the shared `NSWorkspace`, it returns a `NSRunningApplication` instance.

```
var foreground_app = NSWorkspace.SharedWorkspace.FrontmostApplication;
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {foreground_app.LocalizedName}");
Console.WriteLine($"Pid: {foreground_app.ProcessIdentifier}");
```

re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication?language=objc

Comment: Great! Thanks! I would also add that I had to add MonoMac.NetStandard to get required classes

Comment: The second part of my question including answer (how to get window title) can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441936/macos-active-window-title-using-c-sharp/52443413#52443413